# Observable value update changes one bound element but not another

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

My view model has a property who's value updates one data-bound element but not another for some reason.

When `signUpModel.fullNameActive` value changes via the `blur` and `focus` events on the `input` the following:

```html
<span data-bind="text: signUpModel.fullNameActive"></span>
```

is updated, but the following:

```html
<p class="inputTip" data-bind='visible: signUpModel.fullNameActive'>
  Enter your first and last name
</p>
```

is not. Why is that?

Also, when I initially open the page, the non-working element shows, then hides and then shows. As if it's been changed 3 times.

```
var signUpModel = new SignUpModel();

    $(document).ready(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(signUpModel);
    });

    function SignUpModel() {        
        this.userID = ko.observable("");
        this.userName = ko.observable("");

        this.fullName = ko.observable("");
        this.fullNameActive = ko.observable(false);

        this.sex = ko.observable("");
        this.dateOfBirth = ko.observable("");
        this.emailAddress = ko.observable("");
        this.profileImage = ko.observable("");
        this.levelID = 1;       
    }
```

With this view code:

```html
<div class="fieldContainer">
    <span data-bind="text: signUpModel.fullNameActive"></span>           
    <input type="text" data-bind="event: {blur: function(){signUpModel.fullNameActive(true)}, focus: function(){signUpModel.fullNameActive(false)} }, value: signUpModel.fullName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" maxlength="40" id="inputFullName" />
    <div class="inputHelp">
        <p class="inputTip" data-bind='visible: signUpModel.fullNameActive'>
            Enter your first and last name</p>
        <p class="isRequired" data-bind='fadeVisible: signUpModel.fullName().length < 1 || signUpModel.fullName().replace(/\s/g,"") == ""'>
            Gotta enter something</p>
        <p class="isGood" data-bind='fadeVisible: signUpModel.fullName().length > 1 && signUpModel.fullName().replace(/\s/g,"") != ""'>
            This is exciting <span id="personsName" data-bind="text: signUpModel.fullName"></span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the flashing has something to do with the fadeVisible binding that you are using.

Something like this would be a simple implementation:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fadeVisible = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).toggle(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()));

    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) ? $(element).fadeIn() : $(element).fadeOut();
    }
```

Try to reconcile yours with this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/f3XMN/

Both elements appear to be updated properly based on the value of fullNameActive.

Comment: Hi RP, thanks for the response! So i do have a fadeVisible bindingHandler but it didn't work so i tried just visible.. it didn't work either. Now i've updated my fadeVisible to the one you provided and it works.. But why doesn't it work with visible?? Please help me understand ;')

Comment: It should not have a problem with just using visible, must be something else going on.  Here is a sample that just uses visible: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/f3XMN/2/.  See if you can reproduce your issue in there and hit update to get a new link.

Comment: Hi RP, i cannot reproduce in jsfiddle. It's exactly the same code.. the only difference is there is a partial with another knockout viewmodel.. no properties are the same. I have no idea. and again visible doesn't work but fadeVisible does?

Comment: I have an idea.  The visible binding is pretty simple code, but it does not use jQuery to show/hide, so it would be using slightly different logic than the fadeVisible binding.  The visible binding actually works off of the `display` attr toggling between `none` and empty.  Do you have the `visibility` attr set to `hidden` in CSS?  Try using `display` instead.

Comment: hmm thought of that but no.. not using visibility.

Comment: I am stumped then, maybe put your full code into the fiddle including CSS.  I can't imagine that you are messing with the definition of the visible binding anywhere else in your code?  I would doubt it.  Any difference in browsers as far as it working or not working?